# Getting same class instance as attribute from another class

Tags: c++, oop, static

I would like to obtain an class instance from another class.

I have the following classes, with class `A` having `B` object as a private member.

```
class A
{
   private:
      B my_B;

   public:
      B getBInstance (void)
      {
         return this->my_B;
      }
}

class B
{
   private:
      int my_attr;

   public:
      B ()
      {
         this -> my_attr = 0; //Initial value for my_attr
      }         

      void setMyAttr (int attr)
      {
         this->my_attr = attr;
      }

      int getMyAttr (void)
      {
         return this->my_attr;
      }
}
```

I want `my_B` to be exclusive to an object that is instantiated from class `A`.

When I perform the following, I am not able to change the contents of my_attr, because it accesses a different `B` instance everytime I call `A::getBInstance()`.

```
A new_A;
new_A.getBInstance().setMyAttr(50);
printf ("%d\n", new_A.getBInstance().getMyAttr()); //Prints 0
```

But, if I do the following, then I get the correct output:

```
A new_A;
new_B = new_A.getBInstance();
new_B.setMyAttr (50);  
printf ("%d\n", newB.getMyAttr()); //Prints 50
```

I apologize if the answer is so obvious. I suspect efforts regarding making things static or singleton pattern might help, yet I need some guidance, as I'm pretty new to this kind of implementations.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What do you mean by "exclusive"? And what does this have to do with singletons?

Comment: The problem is described with example. Two methods of accessing the private member class gives different results. I want to be able to obtain the correct results with both ways of accessing. Since singletons are classes with one instance, I suspected that implementations toward that direction might help, although I was not so sure.

Comment: You're returning a copy of `my_B`.  If you want to change the one stored in `A`, return a reference.

Comment: When you are asked what you mean by an unusual use of a term, it's bad form to respond with *"The problem is described with example"*. Just so you know.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks for the suggestion ;) But I described it afterwards

Comment: @George makes sense, trying that now.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm can you post it so I can select the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning a copy of `my_B`.  If you want to change the one stored in `A`, return a reference:

```
B &getBInstance (void)
{
   return this->my_B;
}
```